# Expectation of sum of indicator function on uniform random variable

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Let C be an estimator defined as
$$C = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}1_{U_k>a}$$
where $a$ is a real number in $(0,1)$ , $1$ is an indicator function and $U_k$ are uniform random variable in $(0,1)$.
I want to compute E[C^2]. Exploiting the independence of the r.v. i do
$$C = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n}E[1_{U_k>a}]E[1_{U_j>a}]$$
and so eventually I get $E[C^2] = (1-a)^2$. However the results looks wrong.

Can someone help, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result was wrong just because when $k=j$, the summand is not $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{ U_k>a \}})\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{U_j>a  \}})$ but is simply $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{U_k>a  \}})$.

$C$ must be calculated as follows
$$\begin{align}
C &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{U_k>a  \}}\mathbf{1}_{\{U_j>a  \}}) \\
&=\frac{1}{n^2} \left(\sum_{1\le k\color{red}{\ne}j\le n}\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{U_k>a  \}}\mathbf{1}_{\{U_j>a  \}}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{U_k>a  \}})\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2} \left(n(n-1)(1-a)^2 +n(1-a)  \right)
\end{align}$$